Problem using geom_contour_filled function
I have a huge oceanographic dataset (csv file, ~120.000 lines) that I would like to exploit. You can find a part of the dataset below to see what it looks like (it it continues like this until 2024)
#Data
DATE;HEURE;nomSite*;gpsLong*;gpsLat*;TEMPERATURE;FLUORESCENCE;PAR;SALINITE;PROFONDEUR
11/04/1996;08:52:41;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5600;0.1160;999999;37.9900;0.60
11/04/1996;08:52:34;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5500;0.1300;999999;37.9800;2.10
11/04/1996;08:52:27;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5400;0.1280;999999;37.9700;3.30
11/04/1996;08:52:20;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5600;0.1410;999999;37.9800;3.80
11/04/1996;08:52:13;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5200;0.1550;999999;37.9800;5.10
11/04/1996;08:52:06;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5400;0.1610;999999;37.9700;5.20
11/04/1996;08:51:59;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5000;0.1620;999999;37.9800;5.80
11/04/1996;08:51:45;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5300;0.1780;999999;37.9800;6.60
11/04/1996;08:51:52;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5200;0.1760;999999;37.9900;6.60
11/04/1996;08:51:38;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5100;0.1770;999999;37.9600;7.60
11/04/1996;08:51:31;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.5100;0.1830;999999;37.9700;8.40
11/04/1996;08:51:24;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;13.4600;0.1930;999999;37.9700;9.30
25/04/1996;08:06:34;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;14.8400;0.0617;999999;37.7600;0.50
25/04/1996;08:06:33;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;14.8100;0.0700;999999;37.7700;0.60
25/04/1996;08:06:32;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;14.8100;0.0683;999999;37.7900;0.80
25/04/1996;08:06:31;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;14.8100;0.0617;999999;37.7900;1.30
25/04/1996;08:06:30;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;14.8100;0.0617;999999;37.7900;1.70
25/04/1996;08:06:29;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;14.7900;0.0617;999999;37.7900;2.00
25/04/1996;08:06:28;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;14.7800;0.0700;999999;37.7900;2.40
25/04/1996;08:06:27;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;14.7700;0.0700;999999;37.8000;3.00
25/04/1996;08:06:26;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;14.7500;0.0750;999999;37.8000;3.50
25/04/1996;08:06:25;Frioul;5.29167;43.2417;14.7400;0.0750;999999;37.8000;3.80

I want to make a graphical representation of my data, I join two graphs that look like what I want to do. I'm completely lost, I know this type of graph can be done on ODV (Ocean Data View) but I don't know how to use it and I would really like to do this on RStudio.
 
I believe I need to use geom_contour_filled but I have never used this function. The code below doesn't work and I don't even understand the errors that R returns to me.
library(ggplot2)
somlit <- read.csv("Somlit_Extraction_ctd_frioul.csv", sep=";", dec = ".")
somlit <- na.omit(somlit)

ggplot(somlit, aes(x = DATE, y = PROFONDEUR, z = TEMPERATURE, fill = TEMPERATURE)) +
  geom_contour_filled(color = "black") + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Température (°C)") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Profondeur (m)", fill = "Température (°C)") +
  theme_minimal()

The only things I managed to get working are things like that :
library(ggplot2)
somlit_temp <- read.csv("Somlit_Extraction_ctd_frioul.csv", sep=";")

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = somlit, aes(x = DATE, 
                                y = PROFONDEUR, 
                                color = TEMPERATURE))+ 
  scale_colour_viridis_c()

But that has nothing to do and doesn't look at all like what I want to do.

what are the errors you get?

Warning messages:
1: stat_contour(): Zero contours were generated
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: stat_contour(): Zero contours were generated
5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf...
And this goes on forever

What if you convert your date strings to an actual POSIXct date (i.e. somlit$DATE <- strptime(somlit$DATE, "%d/%m/%Y") |> as.POSIXct()) and try again?

The plot does not work, I receive this error : Warning message:
The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: fill.
This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data. Did you forget to specify a ⁠ group ⁠ aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor?
